# How to make PDF of a page running behind windows authentication?

Tags: c#, pdf, webforms, wkhtmltopdf, tuespechkin

I'm trying to make PDF's of some webpages on the same site but since the website is behind Windows Authentication it failes. I can load the page markup using a HttpRequest and WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() but when the PDF plugin tries to create the PDF this is, naturally, without any stylesheets.

I'm using TuesPechkin and wkhtmltopdf to generate the PDF's. This is a ASP.NET webforms solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [LoadSettings](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/blob/develop/TuesPechkin/Document/LoadSettings.cs) class is where you want to look. If the `Username` and `Password` properties don't propagate through to the external resources (CSS, images, etc.) you can try setting up a basic `Authentication` header yourself in the `CustomHeaders` dictionary and setting the `RepeatCustomHeaders` property to `true`.